# Working with react-spring and styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-spring

I can't get react-spring to work. I'm fairly new to this so I have no idea what is going wrong. I'm trying to make navbar appear from top to bottom to 40vh, but it doesn't appear to be recognizing the props passed. I used create-react-app and react-spring 8.0.27

App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const navprops = useSpring({
    from: {height: "0"},
    to: {height: "40vh"}
  })

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {open ? <Navbar style={navprops}/> : null}
    </Fragment>
```

Navbar.js:

```
const NavBar = styled(animated.nav)`
  width: 100%;
`;

const Navbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavBar style={props.style}>
    </NavBar>
  );
};
```

This is basically the code. There are more style props but I guess it's irrelevant to functionality.

animated and useSpring are imported in both files for testing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution,

[Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sping-animated-navbar-1x2su)

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { animated } from "react-spring";

const NavBar = styled(animated.nav)`
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
`;

export default (props) => {
  return <NavBar style={props.style}></NavBar>;
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTransition, config } from "react-spring";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  // const navprops = useSpring({
  //   from: { height: "0" },
  //   to: { height: "40vh" },
  //   config: config.wobbly
  // });

  const transitions = useTransition(open, null, {
    initial: { height: "0px" }, //Not required
    from: { height: "0px" },
    enter: { height: "40vh" },
    leave: { height: "0px" },
    config: config.wobbly //More configs here https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/api
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {transitions.map(
        ({ item, key, props }) => item && <Navbar key={key} style={props} />
      )}
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>Toggle Navbar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I do not think **useSpring** will work on unmounted component. You were trying to animate an unmounted component.

According to documentation, [useTransition](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition) can be used to animate mounting of unmounted components.

The syntax is little complicated, but they have made the syntax simpler in version 9(release candidate) of react-spring [Link Here](https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/breaking-changes/#Transition-objects)